# Regex to contain at least 1 special character but not specific characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to check if the password has at least 1 special character but not & \ ; < >

Password can contain numbers or letters with no restriction on those.

I've tried something like this

```
/^[^a-zA-Z0-9&\\;<>][\"\?/'[]{}|():!@#$%\^\*`~=\+,.-_]*$/
```

How do I separate it so that letters and numbers are allowed, along with the specific special characters, but not the other ones?

Output examples with the regex I tried above:
1!: false (needs to be true, I'm aware my regex makes anything with numbers or letters false)
! : true
a : false
1 : false
!& : false (& makes everything false correctly)
!< : true (still allows the less than sign or anything other than the &(;<>), needs to be false)

Comment: What do you define as a "special character"? Is it sufficient to say it is non-alphanumeric, and not one of the invalid characters you listed?

Comment: This is **not** a job for `regex`. Do a simple walk of the input string and count how many characters of each type it contains (uppercase/lowercase letters, digits, allowed special characters, disallowed characters). At the end look at the counters and decide if the password can be allowed or not and why. It shouldn't take more than 10 minutes to write the code.

Comment: @axiac or just write in a regex in 1 min ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's call `&\;<>` "invalid characters", and any other non-alphanumeric characters "special characters". A "special character" could be matched with `/[^a-zA-Z0-9&\\;<>]/` - that is to say, not `a-z` or `A-Z`, not `0-9`, and not any of the invalid characters.

Now our regex can search for a "special character" prefixed or suffixed by any number of valid characters:

```
^[^&\\;<>]*[^a-zA-Z0-9&\\;<>][^&\\;<>]*$

^                                          -> match start of sequence (prevent arbitrary leading characters
 [^&\\;<>]*                                -> match 0 or more non-invalid characters
           [^a-zA-Z0-9&\\;<>]              -> match a mandatory special character
                             [^&\\;<>]*    -> match 0 or more non-invalid characters
                                       $   -> match end of sequence (prevent arbitrary trailing characters)
```

Test it out:

```css
input:valid { background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.3); }
input:invalid { background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3); }
```

```html
<input type="text" pattern="[^&\\;<>]*[^a-zA-Z0-9&\\;<>][^&\\;<>]*" placeholder="test strings here" required/>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use regex pattern `^(?=.*[^A-Za-z0-9])[^&\\;<>]+$`.

At the beginning of this pattern regex engine use a positive lookahead to ensure that at least one special character (not letter or number) is within the string. Then a regular match of the pattern says what characters cannot be used.

Answer (score -1):

`/(?=.[#!])[^&\\;<>]+$/i` may work for you.

`(?=.[#!])` is a positive lookahead that says match anything and whatever is within the `[]` - in this case we need a # or ! expand that to indicate what you require

`[^&\\;<>]` don't match these characters

`/i` - case insenstive

Demo

```js
const regex = /(?=.[#!])[^&\\;<>]+$/i;

// all fails
console.info(regex.test('pass'));
console.info(regex.test('pass<'));
console.info(regex.test('pass\\'));
console.info(regex.test('pass&'));
console.info(regex.test('pAss;#'));

// pass
console.info(regex.test('paSs1#'));
console.info(regex.test('paSs1!'));
console.info(regex.test('paSs1!'));
```